# Analyse memory leak with VisualVM

Tags: java, memory-leaks, tomcat7, classloader, visualvm

My web application has memory leak issue which is hosted on Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 server. I tried VisualVM 1.3.8 to identify memory leak but couldn't reach to root cause.

**Below is my finding:**

There is a class present from the web application in Generation 1 and has a Avg. Age of 25.0.
OQL query: `select x from org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader x` shows one `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader` for the undeployed web application that has a started value of false.

The `ClassLoader` reference allot of objects.

Is there a way to find out what is referencing the class that is not being GC?
By looking either at the `ClassLoader` or heap dump?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can also try

MAT an ecplise plugin

here is more
http://all-about-java-and-weblogic-server.blogspot.com/2014/02/heap-analysis-by-memory-analyzer-mat.html